# Create VM in Azure from Private Image, and set Managed Data Disk names

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

In Azure, I have a private image which contains an OS disk, and multiple data disks.

When I use Azure Powershell to create a VM from the Private Image, I am able to set the name of the Managed OS disk, but I cannot find a way of setting the names of the Managed Data Disks, how can I do this?

This is my script so far:

```
# Configure the new Virtual Machine
$Vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $SelectedConfig.VmName -VMSize $VmSize -Tags $SelectedConfig.Tag

$Vm = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $Vm -Id $Image.Id

$Vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $Vm -Name $SelectedConfig.OsDiskName -StorageAccountType Standard_LRS -DiskSizeInGB $SelectedConfig.OsDiskGB -CreateOption FromImage -Caching ReadWrite

$Vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $Vm -Windows -ComputerName $SelectedConfig.ComputerName -Credential $Cred -ProvisionVMAgent -TimeZone $SelectedConfig.TimeZone

$Vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $Vm -Id $nic.Id

$Vm = Set-AzureRmVMBootDiagnostics -VM $Vm -Enable -ResourceGroupName $SelectedConfig.Rsg -StorageAccountName $SelectedConfig.DiagStorageName

$Vm = New-AzureRmVM -VM $Vm -ResourceGroupName $SelectedConfig.Rsg -Location $Location -DisableBginfoExtension
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following powershell cmdlet:

```
Add-AzVMDataDisk -VM $vm -Name %name_goes_here% -Lun $Lun `
    -DiskSizeInGB 127 -CreateOption Empty
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/add-azvmdatadisk?view=azps-3.1.0

Comment: But I dont want to add a new empty data disk, I want to name the data disk being created from the Image.

Comment: I've posted the link to the docs, care to read that? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/add-azvmdatadisk?view=azps-3.1.0#examples example number 3.

Comment: I have read this page a few times over the last few days, so maybe im approaching this wrong. Do you mean that I first need to create the disks (OS & Data Disks) from the Image, and then after attach them when creating the VM? Whereas at the moment, all disks are being created, when creating the VM

Comment: `$VirtualMachine = Add-AzVMDataDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -Name "disk1" -SourceImageUri $DataImageUri -VhdUri $DataDiskUri -Lun 0 -DiskSizeinGB 10 -CreateOption FromImage`. this would create a data disk from image and give it a name

Comment: Im confused where I get SourceImageUri and VhdUri from, when these are managed images and manged data disks?

Comment: well, you can always go with the first approach you specified - creating data disks first (as a separate api call) and then attaching those to the vm when you create it. Actually, when I look at the API, i dont see a way to create a data disk from user image when creating a vm (at least looking at the inputs it accepts), it might not be possible (except from precreating the managed disk and referencing it). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/createorupdate#datadisk

Comment: I feared this may be the case, so I assume there is no harm in doing it that way, create the managed OS Disk & Data Disks from the Image, then create the VM attaching the disks? And this will work fine with the OS being SysPrepped?

Comment: yes, I've been doing something like that with generalized images for linux, same procedure should work with windows images as well

Comment: Im having trouble finding the functions to create the OS & Data disks from the image, prior to creating the VM, can you point me in the direction of these?

Comment: I assume I need to use New-AzureRMDiskConfig, with ImageReference, but im having trouble finding what I should use as the ImageReference?

Comment: your image resourceId, I would assume

Comment: I have tried that but I get the error: New-AzureRmDiskConfig : Cannot bind parameter 'ImageReference'. Cannot convert the "/subscriptions/0000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/ResourceGroup01/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/TestImage123" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.ImageDiskReference".

Comment: Also, trying to follow example 1 on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermdiskimagereference?view=azurermps-6.13.0 produces error: New-AzureRmDisk : 'Location' cannot be null.

Comment: they forgot location, just add that to the parameters

Comment: I did try adding the location parameter, but then I get error: New-AzureRmDisk : The value of parameter imageReference is invalid.

Comment: It looks like im going to have to work with snapshots only, and not images, to be able to create a managed disk from the snapshot with the ability of applying a name to it.

Comment: means your image is in  different region, i suppose

Comment: Nope checked this, image is in West Europe, and my script is using West Europe too.

Comment: different subscription?